# WEB API 2 funciona no localhost mas no servidor não

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou começando com `.NET Web Api 2` usando `.Net Core`.

No `Postman` quando faço a requisição na localhost da minha máquina da WebApi me retorna um status 200 ok, mas quando faço no servidor com a mesma WebApi me retorna 403 method not allowed (o servidor já esta configurado certinho, com as portas liberadas e funcionando o Post normalmente).

GET

> > http://localhost:35056/api/listar   (retorna 200 OK  e a lista de usuarios)
> >     http://10.0.0.9:8080/api/listar  (retorna 200 OK e a lista de usuarios)

PUT

> > http://localhost:35056/api/cliente/atualizar/477   (retorna 200 OK)
> >     http://10.0.0.9:8080/api/cliente/atualizar/477  (retorna 405 method not allowed)

ClienteController:
[HttpPut]

```
    [Route("atualizar/{id}")]

    public ReturnAllServices Atualizar(int id, [FromBody]ClienteModel dados)

    {

        ReturnAllServices retorno = new ReturnAllServices();



        try

        {

            dados.Id = id;

            dados.AtualizarCliente();

            retorno.Result = true;

            retorno.ErrorMessage = string.Empty;



        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            retorno.Result = false;

            retorno.ErrorMessage = "Erro ao registrar cliente" + ex.Message;

        }



        return retorno;





    }
```

// ClienteModel Atualizar.

public void AtualizarCliente()

```
    {

        Conn objConn = new Conn();

        string sql = "UPDATE cliente SET Nome=@nome WHERE id=@id";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();



        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", Nome);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);



        objConn.ExecutaQuery(cmd);





    }
```

me retorna a seguinte mensagem no postman:

> 405 - O verbo HTTP usado para acessar esta página não é
>   permitido.
>
> A pagina que voce está procurando nao pode ser exibida, pois foi usado
>   um método inválido (verbo HTTP) para tentar o acesso.

Obs: não estou utilizando  Token pois se trata de uma web api em servidor local com acesso em maquinas locais somente, o post ta funcionando normalmente..

Comment: Consegue colocar o código da aplicação que está iniciando a requisição?

Comment: A requisição está sendo feito Put via Postman, não tenho nenhuma aplicação client que consome ainda..

Comment: @Lucas Onde a aplicação está hospedada? Você tem acesso ao painel de configuração do IIS?

Comment: @LINQ está hospedada num servidor local com Windows Server 2012 R2.. tenho sim, no caso eu adicionei no web.config a seguinte config : <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: @LINQ e resolveu, o WebDav está Habilitado no servidor, na verdade nao sei nem pra que ele serve, caso desabilitar ou remove-lo terei problemas será? li num site que o webdav desabilita por padrao o put e delete, por isso estava rodando na localhost normal e no ambiente do servidor estava dando erro 405..